# Convert datetime to Unix timestamp and convert it back in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have `dt = datetime(2013,9,1,11)`, and I would like to get a Unix timestamp of this datetime object.

When I do `(dt - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()` I got the timestamp `1378033200`.

When converting it back using `datetime.fromtimestamp` I got `datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1, 6, 0)`.

The hour doesn't match. What did I miss here?

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Comment: As a side note, if you're using Python 3.3+, you really, really want to use the [`timestamp`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method instead of trying to do it yourself. For one thing, that completely avoids the possibility of subtracting naive times from different timezones.

Comment: Where does `dt` come from? Is it a local time or time in UTC?

Comment: @abarnert I'd also like to submit a request to purge all codepages and unicode symbols, that is, to outlaw all non-ascii and non-default-codepage languages. Paintings of symbols are still allowed.

Comment: @DanielF: Request denied. I'm not interested in creating a one-world language here, and even if we did I wouldn't want to make life impossible for historical linguists and Tolkien scholars. Unicode already solves the problem, except that certain organizations and products (the TRON consortium, Japanese software that uses Shift-JIS over UTF-8, Microsoft still delivering an OS that defaults to cp1252 for user text files, and various SDKs that pretend that UTF-16 is a fixed-width charset and/or the same thing as Unicode) need to be punished to bring them in line.

Comment: Just take a `int(dt.timestamp())`

Comment: `int(dt.strftime("%s"))` does not work correctly and it shows a wrong unix time. The first one works (well it is the definition).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

What you missed here is timezones.

Presumably you've five hours off UTC, so 2013-09-01T11:00:00 local and 2013-09-01T06:00:00Z are the same time.

You need to read the top of the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html) docs, which explain about timezones and "naive" and "aware" objects.

If your original naive datetime was UTC, the way to recover it is to use [`utcfromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) instead of `fromtimestamp`.

On the other hand, if your original naive datetime was local, you shouldn't have subtracted a UTC timestamp from it in the first place; use `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` instead.

Or, if you had an aware datetime object, you need to either use a local (aware) epoch on both sides, or explicitly convert to and from UTC.

If you have, or can upgrade to, Python 3.3 or later, you can avoid all of these problems by just using the [`timestamp`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method instead of trying to figure out how to do it yourself. And even if you don't, you may want to consider [borrowing its source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/datetime.py#l1428).

(And if you can wait for Python 3.4, it looks like [PEP 341](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0431/) is likely to make it into the final release, which means all of the stuff J.F. Sebastian and I were talking about in the comments should be doable with just the stdlib, and working the same way on both Unix and Windows.)

Comment: if `dt` is in local timezone then the formula in the question is incorrect `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` (epoch in the current timezone) should be used instead of `datetime(1970, 1,1)` (unix epoch in UTC).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I didn't want to cover all of the three possibilities in detail, but I guess you're right, I should.

Comment: btw, `fromtimestamp(0)` might fail if the system doesn't store historical timezone information e.g., on Windows. `pytz` could be used in this case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But `pytz` doesn't help unless you already know which timezone you're in; to do that programmatically, you need a different library that gets the current Windows timezone and converts it to a `pytz` timezone and/or looks it up by name.

Comment: there is `tzlocal` module that also works on Windows. Here's how you could [convert utc time to local time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287083/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Exactly: `tzlocal` is a separate library, not part of `pytz`. You can also do it with `dateutil` and various other alternatives. (When picking one of the many alternatives: on Windows, you want one that maps the Windows names to standard names and looks them up in `pytz`, or you end up with the same incomplete/broken data; on modern POSIX systems, you want one that parses `/etc/localtime` and builds a timezone object on the fly, or you end up with ambiguous name problems…)

Comment: `dateutil` fails in this case (when `.fromtimestamp(0)` fails)

Comment: to clarify: `tzlocal` returns `pytz` timezone i.e., `tzlocal` figures out the local timezone (it supports Windows names too) and `pytz` provides the actual historical timezone data.

Answer (score 191):

**solution is**

```
import time
import datetime
d = datetime.date(2015,1,5)

unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

Comment: it assumes that `d` is a naive date/datetime object that represents local time (it may fail for ambiguous times or for past/future dates if OS doesn't provide a historical tz db (UTC offset might have been different in the past in the local timezone)). [More options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279).

Comment: Looks like nobody minds floating-point solution. Is it that obvious for everyone?

Comment: This drops the microseconds.  Might be interesting.

Comment: Only problem is that you don't take timezone into account.

Comment: it shouldn't. If you need to adjust TZ, you need to do that first.

Comment: wrong in python 3.9.... ```int(mytime.timestamp())```

Comment: For the naive `datetime` use `datetime.now().astimezone().timestamp()`. Works with python 3.9+

Comment: How can I make a **7 digit UNIX** code from `datetime.date(...)`?

Comment: I just had an issue with it on WIN10, so better to use the timestamp instead

Answer (score 182):

If you want to convert a python datetime to seconds since epoch you should do it explicitly:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 04, 01, 0, 0).strftime('%s')
'1333234800'
>>> (datetime.datetime(2012, 04, 01, 0, 0) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
1333238400.0
```

In Python 3.3+ you can use [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.timestamp) instead:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 0, 0).timestamp()
1333234800.0
```

Comment: Doesn't take timezones into account.

Comment: You do not want to use `%s`, as it will be localized to the clock of the system you are currently on. You should only ever use `.timestamp()` to get the correct Epoch/UNIX time.

Comment: `%s` does not work on Windows systems (`ValueError: Invalid format string`)

Comment: any particular reason for the result of `timestamp()` being a float? Is it safe to turn it into an `int`? IE will the return value of `timestamp()` ever return some decimal I should take into consideration?

Comment: When I input: dt.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 0, 0).strftime('%s'), I get error: Invalid format string! It seems to have to work, but why does it not?

Comment: @Daniil change `dt.datetime` to `datetime.datetime`

Comment: @FranciscoCosta Cannot believe I didn't alias datetime! :D Thank you!
I'd like to tell that you can get full time (s + ms) of Unix epoch by writing:
`ms = 1e6 * int(now.strftime('%s')) + now.microsecond`
where `now = dt.datetime.now()` where `dt` is `datetime` module!

Answer (score 55):

Rather than this expression to create a POSIX timestamp from `dt`,

```
(dt - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

Use this:

```
int(dt.strftime("%s"))
```

I get the right answer in your example using the second method.

EDIT: Some followup... After some comments (see below), I was curious about the lack of support or documentation for `%s` in `strftime`. Here's what I found:

In the [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c) for `datetime` and `time`, the string `STRFTIME_FORMAT_CODES` tells us:

```
"Other codes may be available on your platform.
 See documentation for the C library strftime function."
```

So now if we `man strftime` (on BSD systems such as Mac OS X), you'll find support for `%s`:

```
"%s is replaced by the number of seconds since the Epoch, UTC (see mktime(3))."
```

Anyways, that's why `%s` works on the systems it does.  But there are better solutions to OP's problem (that take timezones into account).  See @abarnert's accepted answer here.

Comment: This is undocumented behaviour (I believe). For example on windows it results in "Invalid format string".

Comment: @CrescentFresh, interesting. You may be right.  While I don't see `strftime("%s")` in documentation, I did just confirm this to work on Mac and Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Also, %s gives you an integer, so you lose precision.

Comment: apparently it ignores the tzinfo field.

Comment: `"%s"` is not supported -- it fails on Windows, for timezone-aware datetime objects. You could use [`time.mktime(dt.timetuple())` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27914405/4279)

Comment: Yup, I've updated my answer above to help explain why some systems have `%s` support and others don't. Anyways, I recommend @abarnert's answer.

Comment: @DarrenStone: you don't need to read the source. Both `time.strftime()` and `datetime.strftime` documentation delegate to the platforms `strftime(3)` function for unsupported directives. `%s` may fail even on Mac OS X e.g., [datetime.strftime('%s') should respect tzinfo](http://bugs.python.org/issue12750).

Comment: You should never use `%s` as you will only use the localized system time of the system you're on. You want to use `.timestamp()` if you are trying to get the real UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Can confirm; this does NOT work on the default installation of Python on OS X. It will account for the timezone when it should not.

Answer (score 13):

For working with UTC timezones:

```
time_stamp = calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple())

datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time_stamp)
```

Comment: After an hour of searching, this was the only answer that worked :')

Answer (score 8):

You've missed the time zone info (already answered, agreed)

**[`arrow`](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) package** allows to avoid this torture with datetimes; It is already written, tested, pypi-published, cross-python (2.6 — 3.xx).

All you need: `pip install arrow` (or add to dependencies)

#### Solution for your case

```python
dt = datetime(2013,9,1,11)
arrow.get(dt).timestamp
# >>> 1378033200

bc = arrow.get(1378033200).datetime
print(bc)
# >>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
print(bc.isoformat())
# >>> '2013-09-01T11:00:00+00:00'
```

Answer (score 7):

If your datetime object represents UTC time, don't use time.mktime, as it assumes the tuple is in your local timezone. Instead, use calendar.timegm:

```
>>> import datetime, calendar
>>> d = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
>>> calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
60
```

Comment: Best answer, works perfectly when working with UTC time. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

```
def dt2ts(dt, utc=False):
    if utc:
        return calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple())
    if dt.tzinfo is None:
        return int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
    utc_dt = dt.astimezone(tz.tzutc()).timetuple()
    return calendar.timegm(utc_dt)
```

If you want UTC timestamp :`time.mktime` just for **local** dt .Use `calendar.timegm` is safe but dt must the utc zone so change the zone to utc. If dt in UTC just use `calendar.timegm`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def datetime_to_epoch(d1):
"""
January 1st, 1970 at 00:00:00 UTC is referred to as the Unix epoch
:param d1: input date
:return: seconds since unix epoch
"""
if not d1.tzinfo:
    raise ValueError("date is missing timezone information")

d2 = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
time_delta = d1 - d2
ts = int(time_delta.total_seconds())
return ts


def epoch_to_datetime_string(timestamp, tz_name="UTC", **kwargs):
"""
method to convert unix timestamp to date time string
:param ts: 10 digit unix timestamp in seconds
:param tz_name: timezone name
:param kwargs: formatter=<formatter-string>
:return: date time string in timezone
"""

naive_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
aware_date = naive_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz_name))
formatter = kwargs.pop("formatter", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
return aware_date.strftime(formatter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, when converting TO unix timestamp, python is basically assuming UTC, but while converting back it will give you a date converted to your local timezone.

See this question/answer;
[Get timezone used by datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812638/get-timezone-used-by-datetime-datetime-fromtimestamp)

Answer (score 1):

This class will cover your needs, you can pass the variable into ConvertUnixToDatetime & call which function you want it to operate based off.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

class ConvertUnixToDatetime:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    # Convert unix to date object
    def convert_unix(self):
        unix = self.date

        # Check if unix is a string or int & proceeds with correct conversion
        if type(unix).__name__ == 'str':
            unix = int(unix[0:10])
        else:
            unix = int(str(unix)[0:10])

        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        return date

    # Convert date to unix object
    def convert_date(self):
        date = self.date

        # Check if datetime object or raise ValueError
        if type(date).__name__ == 'datetime':
            unixtime = int(time.mktime(date.timetuple()))
        else:
            raise ValueError('You are trying to pass a None Datetime object')
        return type(unixtime).__name__, unixtime


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test Date
    date_test = ConvertUnixToDatetime(datetime.today())
    date_test = date_test.convert_date()
    print(date_test)

    # Test Unix
    unix_test = ConvertUnixToDatetime(date_test[1])
    print(unix_test.convert_unix())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914405/10197418), except that it's using a datetime instead of a date