# How do i convert the following timestamp(contains utc time) in string to epoch time in python2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp

How do i convert the following timestamp(contains utc time) in string ('2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00') to epoch time in python2.6?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import datetime

FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
s = '2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, FMT)
print(dt.timestamp())
```

For python 2.7:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

ZERO = timedelta(0)
HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)

# A UTC class.

class UTC(tzinfo):
    """UTC"""

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

utc = UTC()
_EPOCH = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc)

def getTZ(s):
    sign, s = s[:1], s[1:]
    h, m = map(int, s.split(':'))
    total_minutes = h*60+m
    total_minutes *= -1 if sign=='-' else 1
    offset = timedelta(minutes=total_minutes)

    class MyTZ(tzinfo):
        def utcoffset(self, dt):
            return offset

        def dst(self, dt):
            return timedelta(0)

    return MyTZ()

s = '2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00'
tz = getTZ(s[-6:])
dt = datetime.strptime(s[:-6], FMT)
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)
print(s)
print(dt.isoformat())
#print(dt.timestamp()) # New in version 3.3
print((dt-_EPOCH).total_seconds())
```

See [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).
You may also want to look at [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/).

Forgot that you wanted epoch time. Here's [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30021083/5386938).

Comment: ImportError: No module named pytz
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> s = '2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, FMT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> print(dt.timestamp())

Comment: hmm... must be a python 2.7 thing. let me try to find a 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: this is the output of your program : 2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00 and
2019-08-01T11:02:28-07:00 . there was no difference

Comment: You missed the last part of the answer: "Forgot that you wanted epoch time. Here's one solution."

Comment: timezone (timezone.utc) is in which class?

Comment: Most likely it's the one from here where it says [Example tzinfo classes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc)