# Using beautifulsoup to extract data that's hard to identify

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So I have a page with the following HTML, its obviously very poorly done but I need to run some automation and part of that includes getting the date below.

```
<tr>
     <td class="bold">
        Last Login
     </td>
     <td colspan="3" class="usual">
        4/1/2011 at 07:01:11 AM         </td>
  </tr>
```

Ideally I'd like to extract the contents of the second `<td>` and then convert it to Unix time but just grabbing it will be enough.

I was thinking this could be done with regex but you would have to reiterate through it a couple times to pull the  contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to locate the desired element with `BeautifulSoup`, I would actually locate it based on the `Last Login` cell text which sounds pretty solid (though I don't know what the bigger picture is):

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<tr>
     <td class="bold">
        Last Login
     </td>
     <td colspan="3" class="usual">
        4/1/2011 at 07:01:11 AM         </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
last_login = soup.find("td", text=re.compile(r"Last Login")).find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)
print last_login
```

Which prints `4/1/2011 at 07:01:11 AM`.

To get the timestamp, load the string into a `datetime` object using `strptime()` and use solutions from [Convert datetime to Unix timestamp and convert it back in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python) to get the timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

last_login_date = datetime.strptime(last_login, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S %p")
print(time.mktime(last_login_date.timetuple()))
```