# Create Unix timestamp given the time only

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I have a time value, in seconds, for example `4:20pm` being `58800`. From this value I need to get the Unix timestamp, assuming today's date. How should I approach this?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start_of_day = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time())
dt = start_of_day + datetime.timedelta(seconds=58800)
```

Like so?