# How to calculate date and time from timestamp

Tags: python, date, timestamp

I need to calculate the date and time but I don't know how to do it. 
The time is in the format `%H:%M:%S` but the date is a timestamp.

The input from the CSV file:

```
ID;      DATE;         TIME;...
110715;  0,448321759;  08:26:22;...
110715;  0,489988426;  09:34:41;...
```

I can't handle the value **0,448321759**. It represents the date.
Any idea how to get the date and time from this?

Comment: When you say 'date is a timestamp' what is it actually?  Seconds since 01/01/1970?

Comment: i don't know there is no information about it. This csv Date contains barcode information of an id. The only thing i can tell is the date should be in range of 09-12-2015 and 17-12-2015

Comment: So your question is really whether anybody can decipher what that field means, but if you don't know yourself then how can we know that the answer is correct?  Do you have the 'real' value for either of the examples you provide?

Comment: @Aehildur If you don't know, you can still give it a try with solutions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python and see if it outputs anything meaningful.
And if it does, write a doc or comment the code for future reference ;)

Comment: the csv-files i got are incorrect. It seems like that something get wrong during saving the files. I got now the raw files from the user and create this files myself