# Performance issues with pandas and filtering on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a pandas dataframe with a datetime64 object on one of the columns.

```
    time    volume  complete    closeBid    closeAsk    openBid openAsk highBid highAsk lowBid  lowAsk  closeMid
0   2016-08-07 21:00:00+00:00   9   True    0.84734 0.84842 0.84706 0.84814 0.84734 0.84842 0.84706 0.84814 0.84788
1   2016-08-07 21:05:00+00:00   10  True    0.84735 0.84841 0.84752 0.84832 0.84752 0.84846 0.84712 0.8482  0.84788
2   2016-08-07 21:10:00+00:00   10  True    0.84742 0.84817 0.84739 0.84828 0.84757 0.84831 0.84735 0.84817 0.847795
3   2016-08-07 21:15:00+00:00   18  True    0.84732 0.84811 0.84737 0.84813 0.84737 0.84813 0.84721 0.8479  0.847715
4   2016-08-07 21:20:00+00:00   4   True    0.84755 0.84822 0.84739 0.84812 0.84755 0.84822 0.84739 0.84812 0.847885
5   2016-08-07 21:25:00+00:00   4   True    0.84769 0.84843 0.84758 0.84827 0.84769 0.84843 0.84758 0.84827 0.84806
6   2016-08-07 21:30:00+00:00   5   True    0.84764 0.84851 0.84768 0.84852 0.8478  0.84857 0.84764 0.84851 0.848075
7   2016-08-07 21:35:00+00:00   4   True    0.84755 0.84825 0.84762 0.84844 0.84765 0.84844 0.84755 0.84824 0.8479
8   2016-08-07 21:40:00+00:00   1   True    0.84759 0.84812 0.84759 0.84812 0.84759 0.84812 0.84759 0.84812 0.847855
9   2016-08-07 21:45:00+00:00   3   True    0.84727 0.84817 0.84743 0.8482  0.84743 0.84822 0.84727 0.84817 0.84772
```

My application follows the (simplified) structure below:

```
class Runner():
    def execute_tick(self, clock_tick, previous_tick):
        candles = self.broker.get_new_candles(clock_tick, previous_tick)
        if candles:
            run_calculations(candles)

class Broker():
    def get_new_candles(clock_tick, previous_tick)
        start = previous_tick - timedelta(minutes=1)
        end = clock_tick - timedelta(minutes=3)
        return df[(df.time > start) & (df.time <= end)]
```

I noticed when profiling the app, that calling the `df[(df.time > start) & (df.time <= end)]` causes the highest performance issues and I was wondering if there is a way to speed up these calls?

EDIT: I'm adding some more info about the use-case here (also, source is available at: https://github.com/jmelett/pyFxTrader)

- The application will accept a list of [instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market#Financial_instruments) (e.g. EUR_USD, USD_JPY, GBP_CHF) and then [pre-fetch](https://github.com/jmelett/pyFxTrader/blob/master/trader/broker/oanda_backtest.py#L68) ticks/[candles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) for each one of them and their timeframes (e.g. 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour etc.). The initialised data is basically a `dict` of Instruments, each containing another `dict` with candle data for M5, M30, H1 timeframes.
- Each "timeframe" is a pandas dataframe like shown at the top
- A [clock simulator](https://github.com/jmelett/pyFxTrader/blob/master/trader/controller.py#L145) is then used to query the individual candles for the specific time (e.g. at 15:30:00, give me the last x "5-minute-candles") for EUR_USD
- This piece of data is then used to "[simulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtesting)" specific market conditions (e.g. average price over last 1 hour increased by 10%, buy market position)

Comment: Have you tried using a date range or Timestamps, e.g. df['time']= [pd.Timestamp(idx) for idx in df['time']]

Comment: Yep, I tried Timestamps as well but still calling roughly 7'000 times the method takes roughly ~600s

Comment: Could you give us a bigger context to it? Are you running it in a loop, with maybe different start and end and the df.time staying the same?

Comment: Exactly. I working on an event-driven backtesting tool with one object [A] having all the dataframes stored and another object [B] which calls specific dataframes on every "tick" (e.g. 15:00:01, 15:00:02 etc.) from [A]. Does this make sense? Else I can put some example code on GitHub

Comment: Well I was getting at vectorizing things. But, since you have mentioned dataframes, so that might not be feasible or even worth it.

Comment: @Merlin I've added a better code example now. A more concrete example can be found here: https://github.com/jmelett/pyFxTrader/blob/master/trader/broker/oanda_backtest.py#L131

Comment: are you calling `get_new_candles()` method in loop (or too many times)?

Comment: @MaxU Yeah, I am. I guess I should prepare the data before somehow (instead of seeking every time)..

Comment: @Josephjun.Melettukunnel, i guess it's the root cause of your problem. I would suggest you to shed bit more light on the things you are trying to do so we could see a bigger part of your puzzle - in this case we can give you more helpful information / solutions as in 90-95% the cases loops can be replaced with more elegant and much faster vectorized solutions when working with pandas / numpy / scipy.

Comment: @MaxU You can find the full code (unfortunately a little bit outdated, but that's why I want to refactor it) here: https://github.com/jmelett/pyFxTrader/blob/master/trader/broker/oanda_backtest.py#L131

Comment: @Josephjun.Melettukunnel, I guess it's the `init_backtest()` causing performance problems as you are using nested loops there. Can you explain what are you doing in this function and provide a sample and desired data sets (5-7 rows each), so we could better understand that?

Comment: @MaxU Added some further info, hope it's more clear now, else please let me know :)

Comment: Why not use a `DatetimeIndex` as an index for your `DataFrame`, that would allow you to quickly index using `df.loc[start:end]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If efficiency is your goal, I'd use numpy for just about everything

I rewrote `get_new_candles` as `get_new_candles2`

```
def get_new_candles2(clock_tick, previous_tick):
    start = previous_tick - timedelta(minutes=1)
    end = clock_tick - timedelta(minutes=3)
    ge_start = df.time.values >= start.to_datetime64()
    le_end = df.time.values <= end.to_datetime64()
    return pd.DataFrame(df.values[ge_start & le_end], df.index[mask], df.columns)
```

#### Setup of data

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """time,volume,complete,closeBid,closeAsk,openBid,openAsk,highBid,highAsk,lowBid,lowAsk,closeMid
2016-08-07 21:00:00+00:00,9,True,0.84734,0.84842,0.84706,0.84814,0.84734,0.84842,0.84706,0.84814,0.84788
2016-08-07 21:05:00+00:00,10,True,0.84735,0.84841,0.84752,0.84832,0.84752,0.84846,0.84712,0.8482,0.84788
2016-08-07 21:10:00+00:00,10,True,0.84742,0.84817,0.84739,0.84828,0.84757,0.84831,0.84735,0.84817,0.847795
2016-08-07 21:15:00+00:00,18,True,0.84732,0.84811,0.84737,0.84813,0.84737,0.84813,0.84721,0.8479,0.847715
2016-08-07 21:20:00+00:00,4,True,0.84755,0.84822,0.84739,0.84812,0.84755,0.84822,0.84739,0.84812,0.847885
2016-08-07 21:25:00+00:00,4,True,0.84769,0.84843,0.84758,0.84827,0.84769,0.84843,0.84758,0.84827,0.84806
2016-08-07 21:30:00+00:00,5,True,0.84764,0.84851,0.84768,0.84852,0.8478,0.84857,0.84764,0.84851,0.848075
2016-08-07 21:35:00+00:00,4,True,0.84755,0.84825,0.84762,0.84844,0.84765,0.84844,0.84755,0.84824,0.8479
2016-08-07 21:40:00+00:00,1,True,0.84759,0.84812,0.84759,0.84812,0.84759,0.84812,0.84759,0.84812,0.847855
2016-08-07 21:45:00+00:00,3,True,0.84727,0.84817,0.84743,0.8482,0.84743,0.84822,0.84727,0.84817,0.84772
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), parse_dates=[0])
```

#### Test input variables

```
previous_tick = pd.to_datetime('2016-08-07 21:10:00')
clock_tick = pd.to_datetime('2016-08-07 21:45:00')
```

---

```
get_new_candles2(clock_tick, previous_tick)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

[image]

Comment: Very nice and 3 times faster.

Comment: I don't understand where to get the variable "mask" from. You have not declared it in `get_new_candles2()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of speculation because I can't test it but two ideas come to my mind.

1. Using a lookup series to determine the start and end indices of a data frame to be returned:

   ```
   s = pd.Series(np.arange(len(df)), index=df.time)
   start = s.asof(start)
   end = s.asof(end)
   ret = df.iloc[start + 1 : end]
   ```
2. Setting `df.time` column as an index and taking a slice. (It may or may not be a good solution for other reasons since this column contains duplicates.)

   ```
   df = df.set_index('time')
   ret = df.loc[start : end]
   ```

   You may need to add some small `Timedelta` to `start`.

In both cases you can do the main step (construct the series or set the index) only once per each data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas query can use numexpr as engine to speed up evaluation:

```
df.query('time > @start & time <= @end')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it out with 7000 rows and unfortuntely it slowed down the performance by ~120%.

Comment: which version of python, pandas, numpy, and numexpr are you using?

Comment: also can you try explicitly passing `engine='numexpr'` keyword argument to `query`?

Comment: in this section it is explained that for <20k rows the plain python version is faster than numexpr:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that using the `ix` locator is faster

```
df.sort_values(by='time',inplace=True)
df.ix[(df.time > start) & (df.time <= end),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that those datetime objects can become very memory hungry and require more computational effort, **Especially** if they are set to be the index (DatetimeIndex objects?)

I think your best bet is to just cast the df.time, start and end into UNIX timestamps (as ints, no longer the datetime dtypes), and do a simple integer comparison.

The UNIX timestamp will look like: 1471554233 (the time of this posting).  More on that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Some considerations when doing this (eg keep in mind timezones): [Convert datetime to Unix timestamp and convert it back in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are already running things in a relatively efficient way.

When working with time series, it's usually best practice use the column using your timestamps as the `DataFrame` index. Using a `RangeIndex` as your index isn't of much use. However, I ran a couple of tests on a (2650069, 2) DataFrame containing 6 months of trade tick data from a given stock at a given exchange and it turns out your approach (creating a boolean array and using it to slice the DataFrame) seems to be 10x faster than regular `DatetimeIndex` slicing (which I thought was faster).

The data I tested looks like:

```
                                Price  Volume
time                                         
2016-02-10 11:16:15.951403000  6197.0   200.0
2016-02-10 11:16:16.241380000  6197.0   100.0
2016-02-10 11:16:16.521871000  6197.0   900.0
2016-02-10 11:16:16.541253000  6197.0   100.0
2016-02-10 11:16:16.592049000  6196.0   200.0
```

Setting `start`/`end`:

```
start = df.index[len(df)/4]
end = df.index[len(df)/4*3]
```

Test 1:

```
%%time
_ = df[start:end]  # Same for df.ix[start:end]

CPU times: user 413 ms, sys: 20 ms, total: 433 ms
Wall time: 430 ms
```

On the other hand, using your approach:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['time', 'Price', 'Volume']
```

Test 2:

```
%%time
u = (df['time'] > start) & (df['time'] <= end)

CPU times: user 21.2 ms, sys: 368 µs, total: 21.6 ms
Wall time: 20.4 ms
```

Test 3:

```
%%time
_ = df[u]

CPU times: user 10.4 ms, sys: 27.6 ms, total: 38.1 ms
Wall time: 36.8 ms
```

Test 4:

```
%%time
_ = df[(df['time'] > start) & (df['time'] <= end)]

CPU times: user 21.6 ms, sys: 24.3 ms, total: 45.9 ms
Wall time: 44.5 ms
```

*Note: Each code block corresponds to an Jupyter notebook cell and its output. I am using the `%%time` magic because `%%timeit` usually yields some caching problems which make the code seems faster than it actually is. Also, the kernel has been restarted after each run.*

I am not totally sure why that is the case (I thought slicing using a `DatetimeIndex` would make things faster), but I guess it probably has something to do with how things work under the hood with numpy (most likely the datetime slicing operation generates a boolean array which is then used internally by numpy to actually do the slicing - but don't quote me on that).