# How can I turn the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss to a unix timestamp?

Tags: python, time

I'm returning information from an API and it uses this format to send timestamps, is there any easy way to return this time as Unix? It returns as a string and all the methods i've tried so far don't work. Thank you for any help

Comment: It's been aswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python)

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks!

Comment: @pyzer it returns the timestamp as a string, how could I work with that?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: @moooeeeep msh gave me a similar answer below, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say somehow you got the time as `YYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS` format.

To convert from string to a time object you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.strptime("2021-11-4T10:44:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Now you have a `datetime` object which you can use to do as you wish. For example you want to convert it to `unix` time format (which @pyzer shared as a comment)?

```
t.timestamp()
```