# How to specify an RRule taking into account daylight savings time?

Tags: python, icalendar, rrule

I'm trying to use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) to create a rrule to schedule an event to run every day at exactly 6PM EST.

The current rrule I'm using is simply:

```
byhour:23;
```

this renders to 6PM during non-daylight savings time, but during daylight savings time it renders as 7PM.

How do I change this to take into account DST?

My server this is running on (Linux) is currently configured for EST and already takes into account DST, so it looks like python-dateutil ignores this and bases calculations on UTC.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested answer in [Get timezone used by datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812638/get-timezone-used-by-datetime-datetime-fromtimestamp)?

Answer (score 5):

You should not use BYHOUR for this.

All you need is an RRULE:FREQ=DAILY *but* your DTSTART needs to be in local time with timezone id, not in UTC, ie something like:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160805T180000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
```

Comment: Doesn't doing this just not take dst into account? The UTC offset stays the same throughout the whole year.

Comment: As long as you have a correct VTIMEZONE definition corresponding to America/New_York, this will take DST change into account

Comment: Anyone knows if the answer is only correct for the Python implementation? I couldn't find this in the RFCs and I wonder if the answer is correct for every implementation.

Comment: @MichaelKäfer Using this approach leads to creation of imaginary datetime on the start of day light savings. https://gist.github.com/ahmedbilal/93e0b846e41b57b24b84f4d538363953

Comment: What if I need to make events at specific hours, Shouldn't I use byhour?