# datetime.timestamp not the same as seconds since 1970

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I think I'm misunderstanding something regarding datetime timestamps.
The descriptions I've read seem to say that a timestamp represents the Unix time (the number of seconds since 1970)

But when I run the following

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1 , 1, 0, 0, 0)

time1 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)
time2 = (date - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)).total_seconds()

print(time1)
print(time2)
```

It prints:

```
1577862000.0
1577836800.0
```

Shouldn't these be the same? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I bet you're based in Mountain Time zone :-)

Comment: There appears to be exactly 7 hours difference. Is your time zone UTC-7?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812638/get-timezone-used-by-datetime-datetime-fromtimestamp help?

Comment: actually, `time2` is correct since both input datetime objects are naive. The problem is `datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)` does more than you think - it converts given date/time from local time to UTC, *then* calculates seconds since 1970-01-01. That's where the offset comes from. As @wim points out, set tzinfo to UTC and you will be happy.

Comment: Note: AFAIK the total_seconds() is also not the total number of seconds (it ignores, AFAIK, leap seconds). (such note is not useful on most cases, but when there are leap seconds, you may see strange things)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, see [technical detail, #4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail): "*Unlike the time module, the datetime module does not support leap seconds.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timezones. The unix epoch is Jan 1st 1970 *in UTC*, but your local zone is not UTC, so when you create a "naive" datetime instance using `datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)` it's offset from the real unix epoch by several hours.

Attach `tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc` to both of the created datetime instances, and you'll see equality.

Alternatively, use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` instead of `datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)` to get a "naive" datetime instance coincident with the epoch.

Comment: I think the problem in the OPs example is not `time2` that uses the naive `datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)` - time2 is correct since *both* datetime objects are naive (= both local time). The problem is how Unix time is derived from `date`, see also my comment under the question.

Comment: @MrFuppes  You're quite right, time2 is "correct" in that it equals `((50 * 365) + 12) * 24 * 60 * 60` exactly. But the question doesn't ask for this result specifically, it asks why they are not the same. I try to explain why the numbers are not the same, and propose two different approaches which will make the results the same (even though in each approach the actual result is different!).

Comment: If there is any problem here, it's probably that OP was expecting `time1 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(dt)` to _not_ account for the local zone but to assume that the naive datetime is UTC (i.e. to get the result of `time1 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))` instead).