# Convert any epoch to human readable format for system timezone

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, epoch

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953715/130427) explains how to convert **any given epoch** to a *non-localized* `datetime`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166400/130427) explains how to convert the epoch for *right now* to a **human readable format** for a *pre-defined timezone*.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1681600/130427) explains how to get the current **system timezone**, but not with `pyzt`, which is used in the human readable format answer.

How do I convert **any given epoch** to a **human readable format** for the **system timezone**?

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18569497/634824) which describes the [tzlocal module](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal)?

Comment: He's still asking for a lot of work to be done that doesn't appear in his code. `pytz` isn't even imported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`time.strftime` combined with `time.localtime` should do the trick. The `%Z` option will output the system timezone. For example:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%Z - %Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time()))
CDT - 2014/07/15, 13:32:19
```

Here, you can replace `time.time()` with your chosen epoch.