# Python: print the time zone from strftime

Tags: python, date, time

I want to print the time zone. I used `%Z` but it doesn't print:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print now.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
print now.strftime("%a,%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %Z") # %Z doesn't work
```

Do I perhaps need to import `pytz`?

Comment: Is that exactly your code? It works for me once I remove the shadowing of "now".

Comment: ....well, you need a timezone-aware datetime, and pytz would work for that, so I'll go with "yes"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`now()` returns an object of class `datetime.datetime`, which does not inherently contain information about its time zone.  (i.e. it is "naive"; see description of "naive" vs. "aware" date and time objects [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html))

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html),

> datetime.datetime.**now**(*tz=None*)
>
> Return the current local date and time.
>
> ...
>
> If optional argument `tz` is `None` or not specified, the **timestamp is converted to the platform's local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.**

To obtain your platform's local timezone, you should use, as you suggest, [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).  [Here's Alex Martelli's code to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681143/how-to-get-tz-info-object-corresponding-to-current-timezone):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>>
>>> from pytz import reference
>>> localtime = reference.LocalTimezone()
>>> localtime.tzname(now)
'Mountain Daylight Time'
```

You can also get the actual [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) offset, in hours, via:

```
>>> import time
>>> print(-time.timezone / 3600) # convert from seconds to hours
-7.0
```

So you could use:

```
>>> print(now.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S, " + localtime.tzname(now)))
Wed, 08-Jul-2015 01:27:49, Mountain Daylight Time
```

Comment: That's because in my code snippet, `now` was not defined.  I was assuming you would first run the code from the question to first define `now`.  I'll modify my answer to be self-contained, thanks.

Answer (score 50):

For me the easiest:

```py
$ python3
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z")
>>> datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z")
>>> exit()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer for the question.

Comment: @pvsfair except that it may produce wrong result sometimes depending on OS, python version. See [details in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31304264/4279)

Comment: Very nice.  Had to use single quotes when using in an fstring

Comment: For prettier output `%:z`.

Answer (score 11):

It is a documented behavior: `datetime.now()` returns a naive datetime object and [`%Z` returns an empty string in such cases](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You need an aware datetime object instead.

To print a local timezone abbreviation, you could use [`tzlocal` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) that can return your local timezone as a [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) tzinfo object that may contain a historical timezone info e.g., from [the tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

now = datetime.now(tzlocal.get_localzone())
print(now.strftime('%Z'))
# -> MSK
print(now.tzname())
# -> MSK
```

This code works for timezones with/without daylight saving time. It works around and during DST transitions. It works if the local timezone had different utc offset in the past even if the C library used by python has no access to a historical timezone database on the given platform.

---

In Python 3.3+, when platform supports it, you could use [`.tm_zone` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time), to get the tzname:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime().tm_zone
'MSK'
```

Or using `datetime` module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().tzname()
'MSK'
```

The code is portable but the result may be incorrect on some platforms (without `.tm_zone` (`datetime` has to use `time.tzname` in this case) and with ["interesting" timezones](http://bugs.python.org/issue1647654)).

On older Python versions, on a system with an "uninteresting" timezone, you could use `time.tzname`:

```
>>> import time
>>> is_dst = time.daylight and time.localtime().tm_isdst > 0
>>> time.tzname[is_dst]
'MSK'
```

An example of an "interesting" timezone is  Europe/Moscow timezone in 2010-2015 period.

Similar issues are discussed in [Getting computer's UTC offset in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168394/4279).

Answer (score 2):

pytz shouldn't be used.  From the help:

> NAME
>       pytz.reference
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      Reference tzinfo implementations from the Python docs.
>      Used for testing against as they are only correct for the years
>      1987 to 2006. Do not use these for real code.