# Transform datetimes in python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

How can I transform a string datetime like this:

```
"2018-07-13T00:00:00+00:00"
```

Into this?

```
"2018-07-13T00:00:00.000000+00:00"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll find this helpful for when you start writing your code:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat("2018-07-13T00:00:00+00:00").isoformat(timespec="microseconds")`?

Comment: See [Format a datetime into a string with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7588511/2745495) and [Python: print the time zone from strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31299580/2745495). (It seems to be a combo duplicate of both questions.)

Answer (score 0):

**try this out:**

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_string = "2018-07-13T00:00:00+00:00"
new_datetime_string = datetime.fromisoformat(datetime_string).isoformat(timespec="microseconds")
```

**and for before python V3.7:**

```
date_time = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

Comment: Nice! But note that `fromisoformat()` is new in version 3.7.

Comment: @UlfR you're right. answer updated.

Comment: Note that strptime parsing directive will make this specific to a certain format in the input string